# Is "$\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu =0 ~\text{for all }E \in \mathcal{M} \text{ with }\mu(E)<\infty$ then $f = 0$ a.e." true for **any** measurable function?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the following (which I'm not sure whether it's true!)

> Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f:X \to \Bbb{C}$ be a measurable function such that
> $$
>     \int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu =0 ~\text{for all }E \in \mathcal{M} \text{ with }\mu(E)<\infty
> $$
> Then $f = 0 ~~[\mu]$- a.e on $X$.

**My attempt for proof.**

First I assume the **case** $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$-valued.

Now suppose, $S :=\{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0\}$. To prove $\mu(S)=0$. If not assume in contrary that $\mu(S) >0$. Since, $S = \{f>0\}\cup \{f<0\}$, so at least one of these sets must have $\mu$-measure positive. Suppose, $\mu(\{f>0\})>0$.

Again, see that $ \{f>0\}=\cup_n \{f \ge \frac{1}{n}\}=\cup_n E_n$. Hence $\mu(E_N)>0$ for some $N$. Now since $\mu$ is given to be **$\sigma$-finite** so there is a measurable subset $Y$ of $E_N$ such that $0<\mu(Y)<\infty$. Then we have,
$$
\int_Y f ~\mathrm{d}\mu\ge \int_Y \frac{1}{N}~\mathrm{d}\mu = \frac{\mu(Y)}{N}>0
$$
Which is a **contradiction** to our hypothesis. Therefore $\mu(S)=0$.
This proves the result in this case.

**EDIT: Case 2:** $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$ valued. It was included in case 1.

**Case 3.** $f$ is $\Bbb{C}$ valued. Then $f= \mathfrak{Re}(f) + i~\mathfrak{Im}(f)$. Now assuming case 2 we get the desired conclusion for this case.

Can anyone please help me to (dis)prove **Case 2**. Thank  you.

Comment: Your proof  for Case  1 is actually a proof for Case 2! Where did you  use the fact that $f \geq 0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Right, right....I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of proofing this: Assume $f \ge 0$. Your assumtipion implies that $\int f 1_E d\mu =0$ for all $E$ with finite measure ($1_E$ denotes the indicator function). By linearity the same holds for linear combinations of indicator functions. You can approximate $f$ by an increasing sequence $g_n$, where all $g_n$ are linear combinations of indicator fuctions of set of finite measure. Then by monotone convergence
$$ \int f^2 d\mu = \int f \lim_n g_n d\mu = \lim_n \int fg_nd\mu=0$$,
so $f=0$ a.e.