# Is it true for a non-$\sigma$ finite $\mu$ that $\int fg = 0$ for all $f$ in $L^1$ implies $g=0$ a.e?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> **Statement:** If $g$ is any $\Bbb{C}$-valued measurable function on a measure space $(X, \mu)$ such that
> $$
> \int fg d\mu = 0
> $$
> for all $f\in L^1(\mu)$ then $g=0$ almost everywhere.

> **Proof.** If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite then the statement follows from [my earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171443/is-int-e-f-mathrmd-mu-0-textfor-all-e-in-mathcalm-text-with-m); since the condition on $g$ implies that
> $$
> \int_E g d\mu = \int \chi_E g d\mu = 0
> $$
> for all $\mu(E)<\infty$.

But I'm not sure how to (dis)prove the last "statement" for non-$\sigma$-finite $\mu$. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why are you asking about non-$\sigma$-finite measures, when your initial question has the standard measure on $\Bbb R$, which is $\sigma$-finite? It is unclear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed  $\sigma$ finiteness of the measure in formulating your result. There exist measures $\mu$ for which the only integrable functions are $0$ a.e. In this case your new statement is clearly false. [Take $\mu (E)=\infty$ for any non-empty $E$].

Comment: ok I understood that the $\mu$ you defined gave the counterexample for my new result (in the non sigma finite case) since: that is non sigma finite and 0 is the only integrable functions so can choose for the counterexample $g$ as any measurable function that is not $0$ a.e. ..Right? But the new result above is true if I add "sigma-finiteness" in the statement (as I have proved that above) without the assumption of "boundedness" on $g$! Isn't that? but you have mentioned "bddness of $g$ and sigma-finiteness"!

Comment: You are right. Boundeness of $g$ is not necessary. @indrajit

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is an uncountable set, $\mathcal E$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of the countable-or-cocountable subsets of $X$ and $\mu(A)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\lvert A\rvert\le \aleph_0\\ \infty&\text{if }\lvert X\setminus A\rvert\le\aleph_0\end{cases}$, then every $L^1$ function is $0$ almost-everywhere, and therefore $\int fg\,d\mu=0$ for all measurable (or even non-measurable) $f$ and for all $g\in L^1$.