# $f\in L^1(\mu) ~\text{and}~\forall g\in L^1(\mu)~\int gf ~ \mathrm{d}\mu=0 \implies f=0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

**My Definitions**. Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group and $\mu$ be a Haar measure on $G$. We have defined "Haar" measure as follows:

> (Haar measure) It's a nonzero left invariant *outer Radon measure* on $G$. An *outer Radon measure* is a **locally finite** Borel measure on $G$ which is **outer regular on Borel sets** and **inner regular on open sets**

(Assuming this definition) the author of the text have used the following statement without proof. But I'm not very sure how exactly to prove this:

> **Statement 1**. Let $f \in L^1(G)$ such that
> $$
> \int_Gg(x)f(x) ~ \mathrm{d}\mu(x)=0 ~ \text{for all }g\in L^1(G)
> $$
> Then $f=0$.

I tried to proceed with the same line of argument as given in my earlier post [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4171443/346939): since each compact set has finite measure, the assumption on $f$ implies that
$$
\int_K f(x)~\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=0 ~\text{for all compact }K\subset G ~~~~~~~ (*)
$$

**Case 1.** $f\in C_c(G)$ and $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$-valued.

In this case I have managed to prove $f=0$.For this let $S:=\{f\ne 0\}=\{f>0\}\cup\{f<0\}\subset G$. With contrary if $\mu(S)>0$ then WLOG $\mu(\{f>0\})=\cup_n \{f>\frac{1}{n}\}=:\cup_n E_n>0$ hence there must exists $N\ge 1$ s.t. $\mu(E_N)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous so $E_N$ is open in $G$. Now I'll use the (weak) inner regularity of $\mu$ to arrive at a contradiction: if $K$ be a compact subset of $E_N$ with $\mu(K)>0$ then we get
$$
0=\int_K f(x) ~\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\ge \int_K \frac{1}{N} ~\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=\frac{1}{N}\mu(K)>0
$$
a contradiction, hence $f=0$ in this case.

**Case 2.** $f\in C_c(G)$

This follows from **Case 2.**

**Case 3.** $f\in L^1(G)$.
Here I got stuck, I know $C_c(G)$ is dense in $L^1(G)$. So there would exists a sequence of members in $C_c(G)$ converging towards $f$. But the members of that sequence need not satisfy $(*)$. Also even such sequence exists I don't know how to interchange the "limit" with "integral"??

Is the original statement valid only for *continuous* $f$?
Thank you.

**EDIT:** If we look carefully the answer given by @Kavi Rama Murthy below, we can get a slightly general statement for "outer Radon measures" on a group $G$ as above, infact any $f\in L^1(G)$ satisfying the slight "general" condition $(*)$ above can be shown to be zero a.e. (provided $\mu$ is an outer Radon measure on $G$): Precisely,

> **Statement 2**. Let $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ is an *outer Radon measure* on $X$. Suppose $f\in L^1(\mu)$ s.t.
> $$
> \int_K f(x)~\mathrm{d}\mu(x)=0 ~\text{for all compact }K\subset X
> $$
> Then $f=0$ a.e.

*Proof.* As I've mentioned above the proof will be same as given in the answer below once we recall the following fact (which can be proved separately):

> For an outer Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$ and every measurable set $A\subset X$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ one has
> $$
> \mu(A)=\sup \{\mu(K):K\subset A, K~\text{compact} \}
> $$

Assume this. Suppose WLOG $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$-valued. Then $\{f>0\}=\cup_n \{f>\frac{1}{n}\}=\cup_n A_n$. By Chebychev's inequality $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for all $n$. Now if $K\subset A_n$ be a compact set with $\mu(K)>0$ then
$$
0=\int_K f \ge \frac{1}{n} \mu(K)>0
$$
a contradiction. Hence $\mu(K)=0$ for all compact $K$ with $K\subset A$. This implies $\mu(A_n)=\sup_{\text{such }K}\mu(K)=0$ and this is true for all $n$. Therefore $\mu(\{f>0\})=0$. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things too complicated. You don't require  any special property of Haar measure for this.

Let $A_n=\{g\in G: f(g)>\frac  1n\}$. Then $\mu (A_n) \leq n\int_G |f|d\mu$ so $\mu (A_n) <\infty$. Taking $g=\chi_{A_n}$ we see that $\int_{A_n} fd\mu=0$ which implies that $\mu (A_n)=0$. This is true for each $n$ so $\mu \{g: f(g) >0\}=0$. Similarly, $\mu \{g: f(g) <0\}=0$ so $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: What if $f$ is complex valued? Take the modulus in your definition  of $A_n$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Just apply the argument to real and imaginary parts of $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Okay I understand. So If $f\in L^1(\mu)$ s.t. $\forall g\in L^1(\mu)~\int gf =0$ then $f=0$; here $\mu$ can be any measure. Right? Here $f\in L^1(\mu)$ makes it possible for arbitrary measure, if $f$ was only  "measurable" then It need not be true for non $\sigma$ finite case e.g. as you mentioned https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4176337/346939 . Right?

Comment: You are right. @indrajit

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much....!!